# @ControllerAdvice and Create Error Message in Business Layer

Tags: spring

Assume i have defined @ControllerAdvice

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler {

 // example
@ExceptionHandler(ParseException.class)
public void handleParseException(ParseException exception, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // return response - error message, error description, error type (ERROR or EXCEPTION)
}
}
```

The problem is where i will formulate the error message text with parameters and also the message type - ERROR or EXCEPTION

Example, Assume file not found exception is thrown for the given file name

Generally, in message.properties file we will be having text as File Doesn't Exist for file {0}

The translation of error message usually happens in the presentation layer.....

Now if we need to pass the error message so that controller advice takes care of passing it to the UI....

Do we need to construct the error message in the service layer before sending ??? Where the exception and the parameters will be binded ???

for example

```
public void accessFile(String fileName) { 
  File file = new File(fileName); 
  if(!file.exists()) { 
   throw new FileNotFoundException(Constants.FILE_NOT_FOUND.....); 
   How to construct the error message with property key and sending with 
   proper error message binded with exception??? 
  so that in controller advice we would just use exception.getMessage() 
  which will have the translated text. 

  } 
}
```

Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a method like below to create a json object and use the same in UI to populate error message.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionProcessor {
//..... 
//.....
@ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public ErrorResource handleParseException(final IOException ex, final WebRequest request) {
    // return response - error message, error description, error type (ERROR or EXCEPTION)
    return _errorBuilder.build(ex, GenericErrorCode.ERR0500, request)
            .setStatusCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value())// error code
            .setMessage("Internal server error") //message
            .setDetails(new ErrorDetailResource.Builder()
                    .setLocationType("system")
                    .setMessage(ex.getMessage())// description
                    .build())
            .build();
}
```

So basically you are creating an object from your exception and passing it back as your response so that UI can handle this error message appropriately.

Now you can design your object to pass it to UI

and you can build your error message in business layer while throwing excpetion or read it from property as given below.

```
 @Value("${error.invalidfile.message}")
 private String parseErrMessage;
```

and then in that method when you are creating a message, use this message

---------Edit 2

If you need to pass something other than excpetion message then create your own exception.

```
MyIOException extends IOException{
 //...
 String exceptionMessagKey;
 //getter and setter
 }
```

Then throw and catch this exception and build your message accordinggly from message and the exceptionMessagKey in the excpetion object.

```
 public ErrorResource handleParseException(final MyIOException ex, final WebRequest request){
... 
// Use     ex.getExceptionMessagKey() and ex.getMessage()
....
}
```

Comment: How to add the parameters to the error message..the {0} and {1} needs to be translated..Do i need to translate in the business layer ??? if not, how to do it

Comment: You should use the thrown exception to provide all the info needed (thrown in the service layer). And you can autowire the messagesource and use it to build the reponse object.

Comment: correct as per Martin, when you throw your exception, build your message reading from properties or as per your need.

Comment: I'm planning to handle in the presentation layer. example, I am planning to send the Constants.FILE_NOT_FOUND key string as well as the parameters as Object[] so that @ControllerAdvice translates using MessageSource. 

i would like to know how to send the response back to the front-end...When i catch the exception and sent a pojo object to the client.it says 500 error. Basically i want the exception to be thrown to the user in the same dialog.

Assume a user submit a form and the exception should be shown in the dialog in the same form instead of re-directing to the error page

Comment: use @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK) if client uses it differently and build your ErrorResource pojo same as to what the client UI needs.